# Boolean OR doesn't seem to work in Youtube APIv3 list search

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to search videos with different keywords. When I use multiple keywords with OR then it is showing empty results.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&publishedAfter=2017-07-07T00%3A00%3A00Z&q=Social+Media+Artificial+Intelligence+Assistant%7CSocial+Media+Artificial+Intelligence+Automation%7CDigital+Marketing+Artificial+Intelligence+Assistant&relevanceLanguage=en&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

When I try individual keywords, it is showing results. Say,

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&publishedAfter=2017-07-07T00%3A00%3A00Z&q=Social+Media+Artificial+Intelligence+Assistant&relevanceLanguage=en&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I tried multiple ways "A|B" , "A | B" nothing worked. Im checking directly on their API explorer [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=id%252Csnippet&publishedAfter=2017-07-07T00%253A00%253A00Z&q=Social%20Media%20Artificial%20Intelligence%20Assistant&relevanceLanguage=en&type=video&_h=16&)

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain with example when 2 phrases are to be ORed.
For e.g.: "When Harry met Sally" OR "Jab We met"

This will be URL encoded as: %22When+Harry+met+Sally%22+OR+%22Jab+We+met%22

You can look in API explorer for the above example: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=id%252Csnippet&publishedAfter=2017-07-07T00%253A00%253A00Z&q=%2522When+Harry+met+Sally%2522+OR+%2522Jab+We+met%2522&relevanceLanguage=en&type=video&_h=6&

Comment: There is a lot of difference if you use quotes, which means exact phase should be present. Im sorry, but V.J your logic is not working for my query.

Comment: OR is boolean keyword to be used in Youtube search query q parameter.

Comment: Doesn't seem like V.J. I've tried this query, even though there are more results for individual queries, it is only returning limited results when we combine both with OR https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&publishedAfter=2017-07-07T00%3A00%3A00Z&q=Social+Media+Artificial+Intelligence+Assistant%7CSocial+Media+Artificial+Intelligence+Automation%7CDigital+Marketing+Artificial+Intelligence+Assistant&relevanceLanguage=en&type=video&key={YourKEY}